# emulator-x86.exe stopped working on android studio

Tags: android, android-emulator

[image: Image of the error]

I am running windows 7 , i3 , 2gb ram,

What will i do

Comment: Not realy a solution more a suggestion:

User Genymotion instead :)

https://www.genymotion.com/#!/

The free version is suitable for most situations

Comment: Thanks bro Let me try !